# How to add a new column in a loop?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I want to add a column in my dataframe. That column represents the number of columns, per row, with no-nan values.

I did this:

```
for i_diagn in range(0,len(df_diagnassoc)): 
    df_diagnassoc['nr_diagnassoc'][i_diagn] = df_diagnassoc.shape[1] - df_diagnassoc.iloc[i_diagn].isnull().sum()
```

However it does not recognize the df_diagnassoc['nr_diagnassoc'], since it does not exist. However, I want it create it in this loop.

Then I thought in a different way, and did this without a loop:

```
df_diagnassoc['nr_diagnassoc'] = df_diagnassoc.shape[1] - df_diagnassoc.isnull().sum(axis = 1)
```

It runns, however it shows a warning:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
```

Any advice, please? Thank you advance!

Answer (score 0):

I can't try it without having the data, but I think this is a better way to add a column with the number of non-null values per row:

```
df_diagnassoc['nr_diagnassoc'] = df_diagnassoc.apply(lambda x: x.count(), axis=1)
```

`apply` used on a dataframe with `axis=1` loops through the rows, and `count()` returns the number of non-null values in that row.

Comment: It runs, but it also shows the same warning that I described in the question

Comment: Does the `nr_diagnassoc` column exist already? If you're creating it when you do the operation, the warning should probably not be there. Try recreating your pipeline from the beginning (i.e., don't overwrite `nr_diagnassoc`, create it anew), and see if the warning is still there. Pandas has been known for throwing that warning more than necessary in the past, but I very rarely encounter it these days. What version of pandas are you using? There are cases in which the warning really points out at a potential problem, but often that is not the case.